# Can I play Call of Duty on the Xbox with someone on the PC?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Can I play Call of Duty Black Ops with someone on the PC if I am playing on an XBox?

Or do they keep them separate?  I could see why they would.  A Keyboard and Mouse seems to give more control (at least to me).  That may be considered an unfair advantage.

Comment: No. Because the PC gamers will kick the bejesus out of the console gamers. Keyboard and mouse is a deadly combo.

Comment: I was wondering why not though. Isn't it possible to have PC gamers play against console? Didn't Final Fantasy do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, PC and XBox cannot play CoD: Black Ops together. PC version uses dedicated servers whereas XBox version uses XBox Live.

Comment: That is not 100% true. Shadow Run is a game that plays cross-platform on Xbox360 and PC. As for Black-ops, you cannot play cross-platform.

Comment: @Tricky - the OP was only asking about Black Ops.

Comment: Im going to reword my previous comment. For the game Black ops you cannot play cross-platform like Bora said, but don't think all games cannot be played cross-platform.

Answer (score 5):

as a rule of the thumb you cannot play FPS games cross-platform. The core of the issue the way I see it is the precision of the controls available to PC users versus aim-assist (legalized aimbot) feature on consoles. This has been a constant source for epic flame wars between PC and console players. Hard to imagine the amount of hate if they were to be allowed to play against each other.

Comment: I agree... users with mouse-keyboard controls would probably gun down 3 console controller users in the time it took them to turn around and face the enemy.... It would be kind of unfair

Comment: Let alone someone with a well built computer (cpu, graphics, ram) compared to someone stuck on a standard xbox 360.